# C Language Dynamic array realloc causes Heap block error message

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, realloc

I just started learning C programming and practicing dynamic array and malloc and realloc. I'm using Visual Studio and the code is in file extension .c 
But I do not know why realloc is causing the error message
"HEAP[Assignment1Start.exe]: Heap block at 01217FA8 modified at 01217FE8 past requested size of 38"
Please ctrl-f this phrase " Here I want to realloc " 
It will direct you to the line where it's causing the error message.

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE 
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

    #define _NO_DEBUG_HEAP 1

    int main()
    {
        FILE *ptr_file;
        FILE *ptr_file2;
        char buf[1000]; //1000 characters array. //if label[10] = "Single"; then label[2] outputs "n"// label[6] outputs "\0" // label[7] outputs " " empty space

        char *vArray2; //is as pointer to a character, to which you allocated memory to hold exactly 1 character.
        int NoOfTasks = 0;
        char **ArrayNo;
        char **ArrayTemp;
        //#define ArrayCapacity 15
        int ArrayCapacity = 20;
        #define ID_LEN 10
        int i;
        int power = 1;
        int quitbtn = 8;


        ptr_file = fopen("output.txt", "r");
        if (!ptr_file)
            return 1;

        ArrayNo = (char*)malloc(ArrayCapacity*sizeof(char)); //allocate some memory that your pointer will point to. //You should always make it point to something or you can allocate some memory that your pointer will point to.

        ArrayNo[NoOfTasks] = malloc((ID_LEN + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(ArrayNo[NoOfTasks], "Quit\n");
        NoOfTasks += 1;

        while (fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file) != NULL) //fgets adds the \n to the end of each line it reads and stores it in buf //outputs to command prompt//If the end-of-file (EOF) is reached the fgets function will return a NULL value
        {

            ArrayNo[NoOfTasks] = malloc((ID_LEN + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(ArrayNo[NoOfTasks], buf);

            NoOfTasks += 1;
        }

        while (power == 1){

            for (int r = 0; r < NoOfTasks; r++){

                    printf("%d %s", r,ArrayNo[r]);

            }

            printf("\n Please enter the task order number");

            int userInputInt1 = 0;

            scanf("%d", &userInputInt1);

            if (userInputInt1 != 0) //0 is quit NoOfTasks-1
            {
                printf("\n %s (1)Add task (2) Remove Task (3)Replace Task", ArrayNo[userInputInt1]);
                int userInputInt2 = 0;
                scanf("%d", &userInputInt2);
                //int result = atoi(userInput2); // convert string to int

                if (userInputInt2 == 3)
                {
                    printf("\n Type in new task");
                    char userInput3[30];
                    scanf("%s", &userInput3);

                    if (userInput3 != " "){

                        int n;

                        printf("\n %s Replaced with %s \n", ArrayNo[userInputInt1], &userInput3);

                        strcpy(ArrayNo[userInputInt1], &userInput3);
                        strcat(ArrayNo[userInputInt1], "\n");
                    }
                }
                if (userInputInt2 == 2) //remove
                {
                    int n;
                    NoOfTasks -= 1;
                    for (int c = userInputInt1; c < NoOfTasks; c++){
                        printf("\n %s Replaced with %s", ArrayNo[userInputInt1], ArrayNo[c + 1]);
                        ArrayNo[c] = ArrayNo[c + 1];
                    }
                }
                if (userInputInt2 == 1) //add
                {
                    printf("\n Add a task");
                    char userInput4[30];
                    scanf("%s", &userInput4);


                    ArrayCapacity += 1;// increase ArrayCapacity by 1 because a new task is added
                    ArrayNo = (char**)realloc(ArrayNo, (ArrayCapacity* sizeof(char*))); // here I want to realloc memory for new element of the array ArrayNo when a new task is added
                    ArrayNo[NoOfTasks] = malloc((ID_LEN + 1) * sizeof(char));
                    strcpy(ArrayNo[NoOfTasks], &userInput4);

                    NoOfTasks += 1;
                }

            }
            if (userInputInt1 == 0) //8 is quit NoOfTasks-1
            {
                ptr_file2 = fopen("WriteTo2.txt", "w");
                if (!ptr_file2)
                    return 1;
                for (int r = 1; r < NoOfTasks; r++){

                    fprintf(ptr_file2, "%s\n", ArrayNo[r]);
                }
                printf("\n You quit the program");
                fclose(ptr_file2);
                fclose(ptr_file);
                power = 0;
            }
        }


        getchar();
        getchar();
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `ArrayNo = (char*)malloc(ArrayCapacity*sizeof(char));` --> `ArrayNo = (char **)malloc(ArrayCapacity*sizeof(char *));`

Comment: `userInput3 != " "` --> `strcmp(userInput3, " ") != 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial allocation is incorrect.

`ArrayNo` is `char**`. And you do

```
ArrayNo = (char*)malloc(ArrayCapacity*sizeof(char));
```

This allocates only `ArrayCapacity` bytes (`sizeof(char)` is 1). And the array actually needs much more, `ArrayCapacity*4` or `ArrayCapacity*8` bytes (`sizeof(char*)` is 4 or 8; let's say it's 4, then ArrayNo[5] starts at offset 4*5 which is already beyond the allocated region). So, when you fill in the array, you overwrite some bytes of memory which you are not allowed to, and luckily `realloc` (in debug mode) has a check for this and stops execution as soon as it notices that there was memory corruption.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would you advise me to fix this?

Comment: `ArrayNo = (char**)malloc(ArrayCapacity*sizeof(char*));` (note extra `*` near both occurences `char`) would allocate enough memory.